# How to make function run with newly selected option React

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I have created a function to calculate the winner between the two selected pokemon. However, instead of using the newly selected option, it is using the previously selected option.

Here is my function:

```
function selectedWinner(){

console.log(pokemonName+' '+pokeOneTotal);
console.log(pokemonName2+' '+pokeTwoTotal);
if(pokeOneTotal>pokeTwoTotal){
    setPokemonWinner(pokemonName);
}else if(pokeOneTotal<pokeTwoTotal){
    setPokemonWinner(pokemonName2);
}else{
    setPokemonWinner("Draw");
}
```

}

I have set it so that it is called in the different select functions, which are on click functions, here is one as an example:

```
    function optionOneSelected(){
   
    console.log('selected');
    axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'+ pokemonOne.current.value)
    .then((res)=>{

      let data=res.data;
      console.log(data);

      let type = data.types[0].type.name;
      let id = data.id;
      let height= data.height;
      let weight = data.weight;
      let name = data.forms[0].name;
      let hp = data.stats[0].base_stat;

      //console.log(type)

      setPokemonType(type);
      setPokemonId(id);
      setPokemonHeight(height);
      setPokemonWeight(weight);
      setPokemonName(name);
      setPokemonHp(hp);

        let sum=0;
        sum= data.stats[0].base_stat+ data.stats[1].base_stat+ data.stats[2].base_stat+ data.stats[3].base_stat+data.stats[4].base_stat+data.stats[5].base_stat;
        setPokeOneTotal(sum);


          let pokemonOneDataList = [
            data.stats[0].base_stat, data.stats[1].base_stat, data.stats[2].base_stat, data.stats[3].base_stat,data.stats[4].base_stat,data.stats[5].base_stat
          ];

          let labels = [
              'hp', 'Attack', 'Defense', 'Special Attack', 'Special Defense', 'Speed'
          ];

          setPokemonOneData(pokemonOneDataList);
          setDataLabels(labels);
          selectedWinner();
          
      


    })
```

}

Here is the function where is it called:

```
  <select onChange={optionOneSelected} ref={pokemonOne} onLoad= {() => this.optionOneSelected()}>
                    <option selected="selected" value="charmander">
                        charmander
                        </option>
                        {pokemonOptions}
                    </select>
```

Comment: Cool wee project! I think the problem here is that State doesn't actually update right away, so when you call your selectedWinner() function, it's still processing it with the previous data. There's a great write-up on how to navigate this here: https://www.daggala.com/react-state-not-updating-immediately/#:~:text=The%20reason%20why%20the%20state,render%2C%20the%20state%20is%20immutable.&text=%E2%80%A6are%20both%20constants%20values%20!,be%20changed%20between%20two%20renders.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I was just wondering how I could work around these methods if the state contains a string value?